# split from headers

Tags: http-headers, httprequest, d

Hey guys. 
I have this function:

i need split headers and html.

```
string simpleGET(string url, string send) { 

    string headers;
    string buffer;
    TcpSocket socket;
    SocketStream socketStream;

    if(send is null) 
        headers = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:"~url~"\r\nUConnection:close\r\n\r\n";
    else 
         headers = send;


    socket = new TcpSocket(new InternetAddress(url, 80));
    socket.send(headers);   
    socketStream = new SocketStream(socket);

    while(!socketStream.eof()){ 
                  //here filter, what is headers and the HTML
            buffer ~= socketStream.readLine() ~ "\r\n";

    }

    socketStream.close;
    socket.close;

        return buffer;
}
```

thanks,advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to split on two \r\n sequences

`string[] parts = std.string.split(buffer, "\r\n\r\n")`

parts[0] should contain headers and parts[1] should contain the HTML

Comment: What if that sequence also appears in the HTML body?  I know that's pedantic, but it could happen

Comment: @Andrw +1, this is my problem.

Comment: Just take the first split as the header and merge the rest.